# Bedroom not getting enough heat

Tags: hvac

I have a dedicated HVAC unit for the rooms on the second floor of my house.  A bedroom at the opposite side to where the HVAC unit sits doesn't get enough AC or heat.  Right now, in winter, that room could be 10 degrees cooler than other bedrooms on the same level.  I confirmed the vents are open in the room.  It seems not enough hot air is reaching that room.   What could be the problem?

There's a supply vent that seems to disproportionately and needlessly heating the hallway and top of the stairwell.  I tried to close the vent but that didn't improve the situation in the cold bedroom.

Answer (score 1):

Try closing all of the other vents, this should blast that room. If not, then that room's duct is either grossly improper, has a blockage or the ducting has separated. If it does blast that room, & hopefully it does, then you'll want to keep that configuration for the most part. It's called Balancing & you'll want to just crack the other rooms & hall to a little bit more open for an equal or Balanced distribution or you may find that just 1 vent (hall) really affects the Balancing. You'll have to remove the grills that don't close & block them with cardboard inside the fully re-attached grill for testing or Balancing & also to repair their operation or replace them.

Answer (score 0):

Look for existing metal handles on some of the feeder vents (these may be partially buried in insulation).  Such handles control flaps, which allow airflow adjustments (this process is called "balancing").

If that fails, then look into an electric duct booster fan, which will draw more air into the bedroom.

Answer (score -2):

Could be your system (vents) need cleaned